# Can i use username instead of user id in wordpress, ignoring wp_users table?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I am aware that wordpress maps the data of posts and comments in the database, with the user id.

For example, in **wp_posts** table, the column **post_author** corresponds to the user id who has written the post, and in **wp_comments** table, the column **user_id** corresponds to the user id who has commented on a post.

But what i am trying to achieve is to have a **username** value, instead of user id, to identify a user. Because i am developing a functionality such that the users will be authenticated outside of wordpress, so their details are not inserted in the wordpress database (**wp_users** table). I am using custom sessions to store the user's session inside wordpress, storing the user's **username** that i receive from a third party site, after successful authentication.

Having said the above, i am considering few options like:

- Using hooks to alter the functionality of mapping/identifying a user by username, instead of user id.
- Creating a new plugin that achieves this functionality
- Create new tables inside wordpress and use them to store usernames along with the posts/comments.

Can anyone guide me in the right path?
Note that:

- I just want to forget **wp_users** table. I don't want to touch it. I will neither fetch anything from it, nor insert anything into it. So i just want to insert user login name into other related tables like **wp_posts**, and **wp_comments**, may be by adding new columns to them.
- I also don't want to change the core files of wordpress, as i am worried that i cannot update the wordpress later. But i believe that the database can be altered though.

Comment: Would be much simpler to create records for your "authenticated outside of wordpress" users in the wp_users table, no? Otherwise it sounds like rewriting wordpress.

Comment: You can set that username as post meta and later use that post meta to fetch post of that particular user. no need to create any table.

Comment: @AD7six My main purpose is to not create new records in wp_users table. Because i don't want to dump it with thousands of users, who authenticate outside of wordpress. After a user gets authenticated, i just want him to mimic a role (that would be decided by external authentication service), without actually storing anything in the database.

Comment: @shasi why _not_ create thousands of users if you _have_ thousands of users? Or create users to represent a role and when they authenticate themselves, assign them that user. Seems unlikely to be practical/possible to do what you ask - but since I don't use WP - I'm not the person to say that with any authority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to. Usernames are modifiable, they are not perfectly unique and come with a host of other related issues.

Split up your application. If you want to have another authentication method then make it authenticate to a user using whatever method you like. Once you know which user it is you can get the user ID from the database and properly generate a Wordpress login.

Your modifications should avoid massive sweeping changes to the internals of a system that you aren't very familiar with. That way lies madness. Instead, focus on building an add-on that does what you need and then hands control back to the primary system as quickly as possible. You avoid duplicating a lot of effort by doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring the user login name by saying username, right??
If so then Yes you can achieve that because userlogin is unique like the userid and you can simply query your wp_users table to get the userid .
If not then there's no way to guarantee that you get the correct user's info by username as mentioned by @mrdoombringer in previous answer

Comment: Yes, i am referring to user login name. But as i said in my edited question, i don't want to use or touch the **wp_users** table. I will only be using the **wp_posts** and **wp_comments** tables for identifying a user by username. So i may want to add new columns to those 2 tables.